# django form filter field queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

How do I filter form's field queryset? After a little search I found that this way it's done. But I am getting an error here.

```
class TbPeopleEntranceRightForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(self.user)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = self.user

    class Meta:
        model = TbPeopleEntranceRight
        fields = ['user', 'area', 'room']
```

`'TbUser' object has no attribute 'all'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
self.fields['user'].queryset = self.user
```

here `self.fields["user"].queryset` expects a queryset where you are providing a user instance.

You might want to do something like this.

```py
class TbPeopleEntranceRightForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(self.user)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = YourUserModel.objects.filter(id=self.user.id)

    class Meta:
        model = TbPeopleEntranceRight
        fields = ['user', 'area', 'room']
```